# How to copy multiple lines of code into byebug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, byebug, pry-rails

`byebug` doesn't seem to be able to handle multiple lines of code.

#### Example

I put `byebug` into the controller, and the next lines of code are (these could be anything, just an example here):

```rb
    payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      amount: @amount_minor_unit,
      currency: @currency,
      application_fee_amount: 123, # STODO
      transfer_data: {
        destination: @star.stripe_account,
      },
    })
```

But it does this:
[image]

If the code is edited so it's on one single line, it succeeds:

```rb
payment_intent = Stripe::PaymentIntent.create({payment_method_types: ['card'],amount: @amount_minor_unit,currency: @currency,application_fee_amount: 123, transfer_data: {destination: @star.stripe_account,},})
```

But this manual editing is extremely tedious. How can I make byebug accept multiple lines of code so that I can copy/paste directly from somewhere like a controller into the byebug-halted rails server?

#### Other ideas

After pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> in the console to exit byebug, then the browser errors, then I can copy code into the browser, but the same thing happens, where it accepts the code if it's all on one line:

[image]

..but otherwise errors with the same syntax error as above.

Comment: what a reason to put expression like in the example into byebug, when you can debug result later by just checking `payment_intent`

Comment: I would say use `step` and `next` instead of copying multiple lines in byebug

Comment: @DeepakMahakale googling now. is there an example somewhere of how to do that?

Comment: @DeepakMahakale from a google search, I think you are referring to [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug), which I haven't used yet, but will continue to look into

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the gem pry-byebug and it has the behaviour you want, you can paste multiple lines of code without it executing right away.

https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug

You can just add it to your gem file and set break points with `binding.pry`

Comment: Thanks! I try to paste the same code in the question (i.e. one command split over multiple lines) after installing pry-byebug and having `byebug` in the controller, and I get the same result.

Comment: Please use binding.pry in the controller

Answer (score 2):

what works for me is Just copy all the code in one and paste it to the browser where we paste the link don't click enter. it will format it in one line. then just copy and paste in the byebug cli.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate the ingenuity, but there are multiple problems with this. Firstly, if the multiple lines of code have comments, it will be put on one line and that won't be valid ruby, so it will still error. Also, it involves moving `byebug` from before the problem, to after it (in order to get the app in the browser to error, to bring up the code terminal in the browser). Upvoted for the help all the same

Comment: if you really need to debug you should do it line by line but for a block for code that should work like I said in my above answer. about the comments you can remove them manually.

Answer (score 1):

The comments have already given you the answer, but I will formalize it here.

Instead of trying to copy and paste the line of code you want to execute, you can just use `step` to take a "step" through the code. [Byebug's documentation](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug#byebugs-commands) gives you a list of commands you can use. Step will run your program one line at a time.

```
def index
  byebug
  init_item = {
    a: "foo", b: "bar"
  }
  // omitted code
```

Entering the breakpoint above, `init_item` will be nil. The command `step` (or `s`) will advance the code one line, and after that, `init_item` will be initialized to what we specify.

Sometimes the byebug will enter a few lines "down", but using `up` (for going up the callstack) will let you navigate to the line you're interested in.

There's no need to copy-paste code into byebug, you can just `step` through it.